# How to access specific element in json and compare the values

Tags: python, json

I am new to json and coding. I want to read a json file and flag the value in "data" to check if the value is below 50 (in python). I do not know how to access specific values and convert them to int.

Below is my code and error:

```
input = '{"data": 47.8,"code": "ABB","ID": "03"}'

var = json.loads(input)

for row in var:
    if input["data"] < 50:
        print(input["data"])

Error:
TypeError: string indices must be integers.
```

Comment: in which language?

Comment: python @silentsudo thanks for asking I forgot to include that

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code, type is already float hence no need to convert it again before doing math operation

```py
import json

input = '{"data": 47.8,"code": "ABB","ID": "03"}'
var = json.loads(input)
print(type(var['data']))
if var['data'] < 50:
    print(var['data'])
else:
    print('No Data')

print('Executing completed')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here (lines 6 and 7) is that you are referencing a string and not the JSON object.
The code below fix this issue.

```
import json

input = '{"data": 47.8,"code": "ABB","ID": "03"}'

var = json.loads(input)

if var["data"] < 50:
    print(var["data"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not added extra things just solve your error which you are getting.

```
import json
input = '{"data": 47.8,"code": "ABB","ID": "03"}'

var = json.loads(input)

print(var)
for row in var:
    print(row)
    if var["data"] < 50:
        print(var["data"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
input = '{"data": 47.8,"code": "ABB","ID": "03"}'

var = json.loads(input)
print(var) 
# >>> {u'code': u'ABB', u'data': 47.8, u'ID': u'03'}
if var["data"] < 50:
    print(var["data"])
```

The above code will work for the input you mentioned. If you have multiple such rows, just iterate over it and use the part as specified.

Also, there were multiple errors in your code, as follows:

1. You are iterating over one entry.
2. After `json.loads(...)`, you are not using `var`, instead, you were using `input`.
3. The variable name `input` should not be used as it is an inbuilt function.

Hope this helps!